# Deleting item mongodb and node async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I've having trouble removing a item from the upload [] object.
The below represents a User, keys[] represents a key for which file uploads get associated with, and uploads[] are files beneath that key.  These are all documents embedded within the User model.  I realize now I'd have been way better off using references but I am stuck with this for now.  Here is the function I'm using right now to find the uploads item,

**______________THIS IS MY CURRENT FUNCTION_____________________**

I'll be honest I am using async and I don't exactly understand it well.  Is there a different async function or way to lookup these items in mongo that would work better? 
Current issues: 1) This will continue looping through until the end even after it finds the correct items. 2) How can I delete the upload item?

```
exports.getApiDelete = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log("User ID found: "+ user._id);
    //loop though user keys
    async.forEach(user.profile.keys, function(item, callback) {
    //verify key exists
      if(item.key==req.params.scriptkey){console.log("KEY FOUND")};
      async.forEach(item.uploads, function(item, callback) {
        //verify file exits
        console.log(req.params.file_id);
        if(item._id == req.params.file_id){

        // DELETE FUNCTION HERE?

        };
      }, function(err){
        console.log('Error during async lookup: '+err);
        });

  }, function(err){
    console.log('Error during async lookup: '+err);
    });
  });
};
```

**______________________________THIS MY USER MODEL_____________________**

```
{
"__v": 19,
"_id": {
    "$oid": "53c812c4e75ab0b013f3c6bc"
},
"email": "fake@mailinator.com",
"password": "fake",
"profile": {
    "gender": "",
    "keys": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53c8130ae75ab0b013f3c6bd"
            },
            "status": false,
            "iteration": 0,
            "created": {
                "$date": "2014-07-17T18:16:42.568Z"
            },
            "uploads": [],
            "description": "This is being run from my Windows Desktop.",
            "location": "Front Row",
            "name": "fake_Desktop",
            "key": "80f94c80-0dde-11e4-ae14-43922f7b8f23"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53c814ade75ab0b013f3c6be"
            },
            "created": {
                "$date": "2014-07-17T18:23:41.777Z"
            },
            "description": "Windows VM test.",
            "iteration": 12,
            "key": "7ad78410-0ddf-11e4-ae14-43922f7b8f23",
            "location": "Back Right",
            "name": "fake2_Desktop",
            "status": false,
            "uploads": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "53c81517e75ab0b013f3c6bf"
                    },
                    "ip": "10.0.1.156",
                    "fname": "hklm_1.txt",
                    "iteration": 1,
                    "created": {
                        "$date": "2014-07-17T18:25:27.241Z"
                    },
                    "filepath": "script_uploads/7ad78410-0ddf-11e4-ae14-43922f7b8f23_1_hklm_1.txt"
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "53c8151ae75ab0b013f3c6c0"
                    },
                    "ip": "10.0.1.156",
                    "fname": "hklm_1.txt",
                    "iteration": 2,
                    "created": {
                        "$date": "2014-07-17T18:25:30.634Z"
                    },
                    "filepath": "script_uploads/7ad78410-0ddf-11e4-ae14-43922f7b8f23_2_hklm_1.txt"
                }
            ]
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove only from array? If yes, use

```
  for(var i =0, j = item.uploads.length; i < j; i++) {
    //verify file exits
    console.log(req.params.file_id);
    if(item.uploads[i]._id == req.params.file_id){

        item.uploads.slice(i, 1);

    };
```

And at the end use: user.save(function(err){});
If there is anything you want to delete from file system, use:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink( FILE PATH , function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Also you don't really need async version of forEach, cause User.findById is asynchronous itself and whole process goes on background.

> This will continue looping through until the end even after it finds
>   the correct items.

There is no "break" for async.forEach. So if you don't want to do unwanted process, use for as I did and append a break point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no async call inside your loops, so you don't need async.forEach().  Using javascript native loops would be just fine:

```
exports.getApiDelete = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log("User ID found: "+ user._id);
    user.profile.keys.forEach(function(el) {
        if(el.key==req.params.scriptkey){console.log("KEY FOUND");}
        el.uplaods.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(req.params.file_id);
            if(item._id == req.params.file_id){

                // DELETE FUNCTION HERE?

            }
        });
    });
  });
};
```